# How to fix a google apps script that previously relied on Fusion Tables Advanced Service v1?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed a number of Google Apps Scripts that previously relied on the Fusion Tables Advanced Service v1 or v2.  Prior to the full deprecation I recoded the Scripts to not use the Fusion Tables Advanced Service but failed to disable the Fusion Tables Advanced Service.  Recently this started throwing an error anytime a function was run through a trigger or by manually running/debugging in the Apps Script Editor.  I disabled the Fusion Tables API in the Cloud Console but continued to get one of the following errors

1. Service Not Found: Fusion Tables v1

   - This is not the exact error.  I failed to capture before fixing and was unable to replicate
2. `ReferenceError: "FusionTables" is not defined. (line 36, file "Code")`

Since the full deprecation, the Fusion Tables Advanced Service no longer shows up under Advanced Services in the Apps Script Editor.  How do you disable the Advanced Service since it is no longer there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may fix this from within the "https://script.google.com/..." project / development environment.

1. Menu pick: View > Show manifest file.

(These next steps are the same as russellkt response, above.)

2. Remove dependencies for FusionTables from the manifest file (appscript.json)
3. (If, like me, you didn't use any other advanced services, remove the whole block.)
4. Save appscript.json
5. Execute your script / verify it's working now.

BEFORE:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{     <====<<<
      "userSymbol": "FusionTables",   <====<<<
      "serviceId": "fusiontables",    <====<<<
      "version": "v2"                 <====<<<
    }]                                <====<<<
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

AFTER:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to resolve I had to perform the following steps:

1. Install [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp/)

   - npm install -g @google/clasp
2. Login to clasp

   - clasp login
3. Clone Apps Script using clasp

   - make directory for files and change to directory
   - clasp clone `scriptId`

     - the script ID of a project can be found by opening the project in the Apps Script editor and selecting File > Project properties > Info.
4. Pull the project

   - clasp pull
5. Edit appsscript.json file and remove the Fusion Tables Advanced Service dependency

   - vim(or editor of choice) appsscript.json
   - remove the lines in the json file pertaining to Fusion Tables Advanced Service v1 or v2
   - original

     - [image]
   - new

     - [image]
6. Push project back to Google

   - clasp push

These are the steps that worked for me on an Apps Script project tied to a Sheet.  If yours is published as a webapp or api you most likely will have to publish the latest version.